# replacement in line php

Tags: php, xml-parsing, str-replace

I have a tag in an XMLlike this:

```
<element name="bar">content</element>
<element name="student">xyz</element>
```

For many of reasons I must modify this XML.

I'm trying to modify code in:

```
<bar>content</bar>
<student>xyz</student>
```

Is it possible with `str_replace()`?

I'm able to do only a small part.

Comment: You have XML, so I'd advice using that to your advantage: don't see it as a big string you have to do string-manipulation on, but use the tools you have (like SimpleXML, etc) to parse your XML, find the nodes you need to change and then write them back to wherever you got the xml in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately I must modify it because i'm not able to retrive the value of a node with a specific attribute (for example in my case "content" or "bar")

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by that. You mean you have a problem with `simpleXML` to parse above XML?

Comment: yes...i use the function $xml = simplexml_load_file and I'm able to retrive the node without attribute but not the value of the nodes that are like <element name="bar>value</element>                                    I have 10 node like <element name="..">value</element>

Comment: I'll give you a headstart, just a sec

Answer (score 0):

You can get the various elements, attributes etc like this:

```
<?php
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml><element name="bar">content</element><element name="student">xyz</element></xml>');

foreach($obj as $node){
        foreach($node->attributes() as $a => $b){
                //you should make a SimpleXMLElement here probably
                //But here is your data :)
                echo "<$b>";
                echo $node;
                echo "</$b>";
        }
}
```

running this outputs

```
<bar>content</bar><student>xyz</student>
```

Comment: thanks nanne..but i can't understand...how can I contact you so I'll pass my file?

Comment: thanks Nanne...now I Understood I Haven't try this is the problem...last thing: I have different tag like <element name="different_value_attribute">value</element> if I want parse only the node with name="X" how can I do?

Comment: Please don't go on adding different questions, this will become a never-ending question. Aside from that I think you should be able to work that out, don't you? As I just showed you how to get the name "bar" in that variable `$b`, all you have to do is something like `if ($b == 'yourattribute')`. If this answers helps you, please consider giving it a +1 or accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this pseudo code for handling your issue:

```
newXml = ''  
oldXml = '<element name="bar">content</element><element name="student">xyz</element>'  
for each element in oldXml  
    newXml += '<' + element.name + '>' + element.content + '<' + element.name + '>'
```

This code of course does not compile, but you can understand the philosophy of it.